# AJAX jQuery form submission with HTML in form

Tags: ajax, jquery-forms-plugin

I'm not terribly experienced with AJAX and so am using some tools and attempting to integrate and customize them. First, this is a wordpress site using an AJAX form to submit a post. It all works great! Now, of course, I have to add a WYSIWYG editor to the mix and need to figure out how to get the html content to submit properly.

Here's the submit code:

```
jQuery("form.pfs").submit(function() {
  // vvv I ADDED THIS LINE!!! vvv
  jQuery('textarea#postcontent').val(jQuery('div.workzone iframe').contents().find('body').html());
  jQuery(this).ajaxSubmit({
    type: "POST",
    url: jQuery(this).attr('action'),
    dataType:'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
      jQuery('.pfs-post-form #post').val('posting...');
    },
    complete: function(request,textStatus,error) {
      data = jQuery.parseJSON(request.responseText);
      if (data && data.error) {
        jQuery('#pfs-alert').addClass('error').html('<p>'+data.error+'</p>').show();
        jQuery('.pfs-post-form #post').val('Post');
      } else {
        jQuery('form.pfs').reset();
        location.reload();
      }
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

As you can see, I've added that first line where I take the content of the HTML in the WYSIWYG (http://elrte.org/) and set it as the value of what would have been the original textarea (#postcontent).

The AJAX works perfectly if there's an error, so it is only the "else" portion of the routine that is throwing the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery.js:2
e.extend.parseJSON jquery.js:2
jQuery.submit.jQuery.ajaxSubmit.complete pfs-script.js:31
F
```

So as you see, I need to validate for malicious code (not part of this help request!!) but more importantly I just want to be able to accept HTML in my form posts. Ideas? I am not 100% sure I understand what is failing and where...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out there was a conflict with another Plugin. tracing out the request.responseText revealed it. This code works just fine.